# How to fix Error when committing to Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I am developing android app that uses Realm as Database but i get an error when excuting commitTransiction() method in Relm 
this is the method that make a crash

```
if (food!= null) {
    foodDb.beginTransaction();
    food.setChatName(group.getName());
    food.setChatImage(group.getImage());
    food.setChatStatus(group.getStatus());
    foodDb.commitTransaction();
        }
```

and this is the logcat Error I got :

```
11-30 23:15:06.486 4480-4480/com.yourapp.chatapp E/REALM_JNI: jni: ThrowingException 2, Out of range  in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsList.cpp line 135(requested: 4294967295 valid: 0), .
Exception has been thrown: Out of range  in /Users/cm/Realm/realm- 
    java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsList.cpp line 
    135(requested: 4294967295 valid: 0)
     11-30 23:15:06.496 4480-4480/com.yourapp.chatapp E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
 11-30 23:15:06.496 4480-4480/com.yourapp.chatapp A/libc: Fatal signal 6 
   (SIGABRT) at 0x00001180 (code=-6), thread 4480 (yourapp.chatapp)
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any lists in this example here. I'm pretty sure the error is elsewhere. It sounds like you are passing `Integer.VALUE_MAX` to a `realmList.get()` call. It would also be nice to know what version of Realm is being used.

Comment: can you post your `Food` class ?